# Mongo document versions array with draft version

Tags: mongodb

I am dealing with a CMS like system using MongoDB. Each item is meant to be versioned and there should also be a draft version. Most of the time we are interested in only the current published version.

So, I have been thinking following:

```
{
   _id: "42",
   current: {
     name: "item1",
     detail: "baz"
   },
   draft: {
     name: "item1",
     detail: "draft stuff"
   },
   versions: [
                {
                  version: "1",
                  name: "item1"
                  detail: "foo"
                },
                {
                  version: "2",
                  name: "item1"
                  detail: "bar"
                }
              ]
 }
```

Creation of new current would go through 'draft' first and at the publishing stage it would replace current and old current would move to the array of versions. Similarly, rollback to an old version would happen by making a copy to draft.

Does that make sense in context of MongoDB? Should I keep versions as an array in the same document as the current item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing structure of the documents in MongoDB the easiest way is to think about the access patterns and data locality.

Do you need all the versions *every* time you load a document? Does it make more sense to separate the versions in separate collection?
Also you need to think about updating / inserting documents. If you have two separate collections it will be harder to guarantee consistency between them (vs. everything in one document/collection).

Also, you didn't specify the size of the data and how often will the versions change. If a document will be huge (a lot of data and versions) you need to think about the limit of 16MB per document.

To answer your question - the structure you proposed makes sense but you need to think about how does it fit to your app.

Answer (score 2):

Really, I think if you need versions like a key feature of your document - you probably need to take a look to CouchDB - they have documents version out of the box and it's very easy to operate with them, with super smalls development efforts (much less then you will need for MonogoDB)

Talking about your case in specific, I think that your solutions is just fine, unless amount of versions of your document will be super huge (because documents are limited).